# Angular App: Using two domains to point into same app's different states to use as home page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am planning to build a web application in AngularJS using Node JS and MonogoDB. Here I am confused a little bit, the basic functionality of the app will be:

**1.** sell used cars by owners on my portal and

**2.** Buyers can search for cars to buy.

Two domains I am going to use will be like:

**A.)** *Sellyourcar.com* and
**B.)** *searchusedcar.com*

My requirement is that,

***1. Sellyourcar.com***: Home page should be the view A.html, I have created in my app

***2. searchusedcar.com*** Home page should be another view like B.html, I have created in same app

As a beginner, my question is that is it possible to meet my requirements without creating two different app or by simply using a single app? If possible can someone explain how to set the routes to achieve this feature?

Comment: Are majority of your code(not only views, but js codes too) reusable? If yes, use `example.com/sellyourcar` and `example.com/searchusedcar` is better (single app). Else, its better to have two different apps sitting on two different domains - easier to manage your host server too (nodejs)

Comment: Didnt get this: You want to have 2 different sites, they are related somehow - or you want just to reuse your code?

Comment: @CozyAzure :  I have same code to reuse. To make it even more clear I have two views in my called view1.html and view2.html both views are available in the two domains. View1 is the home page for 1st domain and View2 is the home page for 2nd domain.